# r kmeans consistent order of clusters in repeated runs

Tags: r, k-means

I am doing kmeans clustering using r and I am finding it hard to label the clusters everytime I knit my R Markdown document as the ordering of the clusters keep changing.

For example, when I knit the document the 1st time:

```
set.seed(100)
k4 <- kmeans(steps_matrix, centers = 4, nstart = 50)
table(cluster)

1   2   3   4 
140 399  33 198
```

Lets say I label the clusters as A,B,C,D respectively. But the next time I knit the document:

```
set.seed(100)
k4 <- kmeans(steps_matrix, centers = 4, nstart = 50)
table(cluster)

1   2   3   4 
399 198  33 140
```

So now although the cluster sizes are the same, the labels A,B,C,D do not correspond to cluster 1,2,3,4. Is there anyway to keep them consistent between runs? Does kmeans have an option to sort the cluster by sizes and then labelling them 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Are you sure? I created a dummy matrix to work with (you should add a sample of your data to make this reproducible), and added it with your code to an rmarkdown doc. Knit it a couple times and it comes out identical. Is your matrix definitely the same from one rendering to the next?

Comment: Also, if you want the clusters labeled based on size, you could do that yourself

Comment: Matrix is definitely consistent. Just running the above 6 lines in succession produces different results.

Comment: Give us an example of the data that illustrates the issue. Using `set.seed(100)` before `kmeans()` should give identical results.

Comment: Do you have seeds in each Rmarkdwon chunk or in setup?